# Check if href linked page exists

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a charming way to check whether a link on a page leads to a page that returns a HTML 200 code? I want to allow users to set their own links in a model but also i want to prevent links that leads to a 500 or 404 page.

One way, i think, is to check given links in the controller on every page request and examen the return code (with http-party) of that link. And than react according to that result.

Model (schema.rb):

```
create_table "teaser_items" do |t|
    t.string   "text",     limit: 255
    t.string   "link",     limit: 255
    ...
end
```

Controller:

```
def show
   # only if TeaserItem link is valid
   @teaser_items = TeaserItems.where(active: true).order(:position)
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With ruby stdlib you can do following:

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse(@teaser_item.link)
response = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.request_head(url.path)
p response.status # check if 200 or 201
```

With Faraday gem:

```
Faraday.head(@teaser_item.link).status == 200
```